# How do I know my frame can take a compact crank set?

Tags: crankset

My bike came with only RD as 1 x 9 drive system. But the frame does have a FD mount point and the seller told me 53/39 can go on it for sure but he is not sure if the compact will work. So how do I know it, anything to measure? My bike has Shimano Sora 9 speed RD, cassette, chain, rear shifter. I have measured the BB shell and it has 68 mm length and 40 mm diameter, based on my limited research it's a BSA standard. My current crank is a 56 T single chain ring and it's square taped. BTW, my bike is a 20 inch folder so don't be surprised by the 56 T chain ring.

And Can I just add a smaller chain ring to the inner of the current big one to make a 56/39 set up? I have no experience on this at all so forgive me if this is absurd. I used to have 2 bikes with triple chain rings but never took a deep look at the things so can't remember what a double or triple looks like.

Update: I now know my FD mount is a braze on because it's a tab welded on the seat post. I measured the length between the lowest edge of the hole in the tab to the center of the BB shell, it's about 14 cm. The length of the hole is 2.5 cm. So can a FD reaches the chain rings on a compact?
Here is pic of the FD area, the tab is marked in the red circle.

[image]

Comment: If you have  56 T now then why do you want a compact?   Why would you want smaller than 39 on 20 inch?

Comment: Because that give me gear inch of 35 lowest, and I am planning for some tour which covers some really hilly area.

Comment: That is not adding up to me.  Your biggest gear in back is 22?  Even the SS will take a 32T / 14T.

Comment: My cassette is 11-28 T. 406 Rim size, 56T chain ring give me 35.6 - 90.6 gear inches (23 mm width tyres). I know I can change to a MTB cassette , but even at 36 T still can't get a low enough gear inch (27.8) and also need to change RD to long cage for that, which is a little bit too close to the ground because of the 20 inch wheel size.

Comment: Not the number I am getting. 39 32 gear inch of 21.7. Why do you have to have a compact?  bikecalc.com/gear_inches Add SS is short cage http://bike.shimano.com/content/sac-bike/en/home/components11/road/sora1.html What makes you so sure you can go smaller than a 39 with a short cage?

Comment: My current biggest cog is 28, and I heard for a loaded tour I need 20 gear inch lowest for the worst. So if I get 50/34 I can get lowest at 21.5 without changing Cassette. The short cage RD has capacity of 37 T, which is enough (50-34 + 28 -11 = 33), also the max front diff = 16, which is also fine (50 -34 = 16). That's why I want to go a compact.

Comment: All that because you don't want to change out a cassette? And you are doing loaded touring on that bike?

Comment: Yes, the reason I have said, even I change to a 36 T, for current 56 T ring it's still too high and I have to change RD as well. I can change the 56 T ring  to a smaller one but then I lose the high range. So I will go to a double, and if  I change the crank set, I want to keep other stuff as much as possible. Yes, I want to do it on a folder, for FUN. If you Google it you can find some people have done that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/23933/discussion-between-blam-and-thotwielder).

Answer (score 2):

The most likely complication is that proper shifting using a compact crank set requires that the front derailleur sit lower on the seat tube. If your frame has a braze-on mount for the front derailleur it is likely too high to work with bolt on derailleur, and may get in the way if you try to use a bracket-mount front derailleur.

Comment: I updated with more info.

Comment: If the frame will fit a 56/39, then there should be no frame clearance problems with a compact crank. My guess is that the FD should work fine

Comment: I also think the FD should work just fine. These can be vertically adjusted and, more important, if it didn't the FD mount simply wouldn't be there.